# Who picks up events dispatched to the event flow in AS3?

Tags: flash, events, actionscript

Let me preface this by saying that I have absolutely no idea about AS3, Flash or anything alike, hence my troubles, I do have general prorgramming experience though so I'm familiar with the basic concepts.

I'm currently reverse engineering an SWF to understand and possibly modify its behaviour. I have decompiled the source and dug through it in order to find out what exaclty happens when a specific button is clicked.

I have narrowed it down to the following:

```
     var _loc2_:ILandingPageContext = getFirstContext(ILandingPageContext);
     logger.logDebug(_loc2_ + " try to join game");
     var _loc3_:String = JSON.stringify(this._model.getCurrentFeaturedGame());
     _loc2_.getSharedEvents().dispatchEvent(new DataEvent("spectateFeaturedGame",true,false,_loc3_));
```

From reading the AS documentation I gathered that this dispatches the DataEvent to the event flow - I'm guessing there now is an event called "spectateFeaturedGame" floating around.

Now I'm totally lost though. What is gonna happen next ? I imagine there has to be someone to pick up this event somewhere and act accordingly, but I have no idea where to search.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction to find out what exactly happens when this event is dispatched ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really tell who will capture the event, if you are navigating someone else code - that is a loose coupling with all its advantages and disadvantages.

Best thing you might do is to search the source code for "spectateFeaturedGame" phrase. It will probably be used in place when someone adds an event listener. Looking up the "addEventListener" syntax should give you an idea how it works.

Comment: I have already searched for the phrase and it doesn't appear anywhere else in the code, so it has to be in another file I guess ... is there a way to find out which file that might be ?

Comment: That depends on what IDE you are using. If after decompiling you are getting multiple .as files, then any program that allows you to search multiple files should be fine - for example in Notepad++ you can press CTRL+F to "find in files".

Answer (score 0):

When events are dispatched in Flash, there's 2 things that can happen, depending on if the Object listening for the event is on the DisplayList or not.

**No Display List:**
This is the simplest case, events are dispatched directly to listeners (each object has an internal list of listeners).

**Display List:**
These are events like mouse click, keyboard events etc. Events are dispatched to the Stage, where they travel down through the display list until they get to your object:

```
(click event)
Stage
    - Parent
        - Child (listener)
```

The phase Stage->Parent is known as the capture phase. The event then hits your child. Then it goes back up the display list (this time in Parent->Stage) order. This is the bubble phase.

The docs for `addEventListener()` in AS3 are here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener()

You can read more about the event flow here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e4f.html

For your particular case, if you want to find the listening object, do as quarion suggested and search for "addEventListener" or better yet "spectateFeaturedGame"